# How to display WebView in Delphi XE5

Tags: android, webview, delphi-xe5

I want to use WebView from Java, but I cant see it on the display. In Eclipse is all in xml, I didnt find any tutorial for it.

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  myWebView: JWebView;
begin
  CallInUiThread(
    procedure
    begin
        myWebView := TJWebView.JavaClass.init(SharedActivityContext);
        myWebView.loadUrl(StringToJString('https://accounts.google.com'));
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(TJWebViewClient.Create());
        myWebView.setMinimumHeight(400);
        myWebView.setMinimumWidth(400);
        MyWebView.setX(0);
        MyWebView.setY(0);
        MyWebView.setTop(0);
        Sleep(3000);
   end);
```